# Can't resolve error while moving files from one directory to another directory with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I have a question that
"Create a program that read the names of files in directory 'Task2' the names are in format UmSn where `m=1 to 40` and `n=1 to 40` separate the files into different directories based on `m` like `U1,U2,U3......U40`."
Hints: use 'os' module for reading directories and filenames.
I tried to solve it but can't.
Here is my code.

```
import shutil
import os,fnmatch
os.chdir("D:/MCS 2/MCS4/SL/Task2")
for i in range(1,41):
    os.mkdir("U"+str(i))
files = os.listdir()
pattern = "*.TXT"

for i in range(1,41):
    for f in files:
        if f.startswith("U"+str(i)) and fnmatch.fnmatch(f, pattern):
            shutil.move(f,("U"+str(i)))
```

I tried a lot but can't resolve this error.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kaleemi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 557, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'U10S1.TXT' -> 'U10\\U10S1.TXT'
```

Files start with`U1 T0 U9` moves successfully but generate error while moving `U10S1.TXT`.
Hence the file also `U10S1.TXT`exist in directory.
Please help me to find where I am doing wrong in my code.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the path to files.

Comment: Shouldn't this statement have back slashes?
`os.chdir("D:\MCS 2\MCS4\SL\Task2")`

Comment: No problem with `os.chdir("D:/MCS 2/MCS4/SL/Task2")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try making sure you provide the absolute path instead with [`os.path.abspath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

```
from os.path import abspath
...
shutil.move(abspath(f),("U"+str(i)))
```